# 2nd stage SQL Injection

Tags: php, mysql

I have a user form that is sent to an external website and the response from that website contains a unique code (like "a87ju89y"). That code is important to me and so, using prepared statements I input it into my database.

On the back end I have a cronjob that runs a php script every minute that queries the database to see if there are new codes like this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,  $database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT user FROM stack ORDER BY ID");
$cronresults = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT run FROM kook ORDER BY ID");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
$cron = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cronresults);
$row2 = $row['user'];
$cron2 = $cron['kook'];
```

My question is that would I need a prepared statement to simply pull information and prevent some sort of SQL injection? and if I do how would I go about it?

Comment: The second level injection occurs when you use the data already in your DB directly in another query. Say you did `select userdata from table` then did `delete from userdata where userid = ' . $row['userdata']`, expecting `userdata` to be an id but it actually had `0 or 1=1`. Now all data would be gone. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Second_order_SQL_injection

Comment: okay makes sense, thank you!

Comment: Pretty much anytime you are passing a value to SQL use a parameterized query, don't just pass it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a prepared statement here because you're not passing any data into the query. Prepared statements break the query into the query itself(with placeholders) and the data to be processed. This way there's no confusion what is data and what is query.

Selecting all rows in a table requires no data.

Comment: Great! real simple answer I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Prepared statement are only useful when you need to plug values into a query. This is typically when you have a `WHERE` clause that includes values to search for.  In your case, neither query has any moving parts, so there is nothing prepared statements can do for you.

On a side note, you can do a couple of things to improve your script:

- combine the two queries into one for efficiency:
- Always check that the query was run successfully before you fetch results
- Add `LIMIT 1` at the end of the SQL if you will only use the first result

Comment: thanks for the suggestions! im not sure how to go about 1 and 2 any documentation i can refer to?

Comment: @electricjelly Are the `ID` fields in the two tables (what you `order by`) referring to the same thing?

Comment: no they are both just autonumber fields no connection between the two